# Approximate an integrable function almost-everywhere boundedly with functions of compact support

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, measurable-functions

It is clear that any measurable function can be approximated pointwise boundedly by a sequence of simple functions, and it is not hard to understand that any integrable function can be approximated in $L^p$ by continuous functions with finite support.

However, when the conditions are combined together, I wonder if the following statement is true:

Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function and suppose that $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$, then for any $\delta \gt 0$ there exists a non-negative continuous function with compact support, note as $h_\delta$, such that

(1) $\int |f(x)|^p dx - \delta^p \le \int|h_\delta(x)|^pdx$ and

(2) $h_\delta(x)\le f(x)$ for a.e. $x\in \Bbb R^n$.

Could anyone help me by giving either a direct proof or a counterexample to the statement? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Take $f$ to the characteristic function of a  fat Cantor set for a counter-example. In this case $h_{\delta}\equiv 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you help me with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574262/counter-example-approximate-a-non-negative-integrable-function-from-below-by-a) about your hint?