# Counter-example: approximate an integrable function from below by a continuous function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

I'm reading [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533217/approximate-an-integrable-function-almost-everywhere-boundedly-with-functions-of) in which the OP asked if the following statement is true, i.e.,

> Let $f$ be a **non-negative** measurable function and suppose that $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$, then for any $\delta \gt 0$ there exists a **non-negative** continuous function with compact support, note as $h_\delta$, such that
>
> (1) $\int |f(x)|^p dx - \delta^p \le \int|h_\delta(x)|^pdx$ and
>
> (2) $h_\delta(x)\le f(x)$ for **a.e.** $x\in \Bbb R^n$.

Then @geetha290krm [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533217/approximate-an-integrable-function-almost-everywhere-boundedly-with-functions-of#comment9528211_4533217) that

> Take $f$ to the characteristic function of a fat Cantor set for a counter-example. In this case $h_\delta \equiv 0$.

I'm trying to formalize @geetha290krm's idea as follows.

> Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $E := [0, 1]$. We work with $L_1 (E, \lambda, \mathbb R_{\ge 0})$. Let $C$ be the fat Cantor set. Then $\lambda(C)>0$. Let $f := 1_C$. Then $f=0$ on $E \setminus C$. Because $h_\delta (x) \le f (x)$ for $\lambda$-a.e. $x \in E$, there is a $\lambda$-null subset $N$ of $E$ such that $h_\delta \le f$ on $E \setminus N$. It follows that $h_\delta = 0$ on $E \setminus  (C\cup N)$ and thus on $E \setminus  (\overline C \cup N)$. Because $h_\delta$ is continuous, we get $h_\delta=0$ on $\overline{E \setminus (\overline C \cup N)}$. Because $C$ is nowhere dense, we get
> $$
> \overline{E \setminus \overline C} = E
> \quad \text{and thus} \quad
> \lambda \left ( \overline{E \setminus \overline C}  \right ) = 1.
> $$
> To show that $h_\delta=0$ $\lambda$-a.e., it suffices to show that
> $$
> \lambda \left ( \overline{E \setminus  (\overline C \cup N)} \right ) = 1.
> $$

Then I got stuck. Could you elaborate how finish the proof?

Comment: If a continuous function is positive at a point, it is positive in an open set containing that point. But the fat Cantor set has an empty interior.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Let $N$ be a null subset of $E$ such that $h_\delta \le f$ on $E \setminus N$. Assume that $h_\delta (a)>0$ for some $a \in E$. By continuity of $h_\delta$, there is an open interval $I$ such that $h_\delta (x)>0$ for all $x \in I$. As such, $f>0$ on $I \setminus N$. So $I \setminus N \subset C$. We have $C$ contains no interval, but we don't know if $I \setminus N$ is an interval. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some details to my comment above:

If a continuous function is positive at a point it is positive in an open interval $I$ containing that point.

Thus, as noted in a comment by the OP, it suffices to show that an open interval $I$ is not contained in the union $C \cup N$, where $C$ is a fat Cantor set    and $N$ is a Lebesgue null set.

Now $I \setminus C$ is nonempty and open, so it contains an open interval $J$, which cannot be covered by $N$.